# blackberry - using sessions?

Tags: blackberry

I am very new to this Blackberry application. How can we use sessions in this application?
When moving from login page to another one; how can I use sessions to get the user name in the next page also?

Comment: have you tried : http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/

Comment: Not nearly enough information.  If you won't spend the time asking a question properly why would you think other people will invest their time in responding?

Comment: Please explain ur question in detail

Comment: Are you talking about application you're developing? What technology you're using?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about creating using Java to create an application for the Blackberry then you can't use Session.

One way that you can use it if it is only to pass 1 value from a screen to the next is to add a parameter to the constructor of the screen that you are navigation too:

```
public class aScreen extends MainScreen{
  public aScreen(String userName){
  }
}
```

then when navigating to that screen use:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new aScreen("Rateesh"));
```

If it's to share a value across multiple screens then you can use a global variable declared in the class that is the main entry point for the application, which extends UiApplication or Application.